# How to fill custom colors in jqxGrid (jqwidget) cells by changing the cell value?

Tags: dynamic, cell, background-color, jqxgrid, jqwidget

How to fill **custom colors** in  **jqxGrid (jqwidget) cells** dynamic by changing the cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the background color of a cell based on the value, you can just use a custom renderer for the column.

```
cellsrenderer: function(row, column, value) {
  var color = getColorForValue(value),     //function you write to determine the color
      display = getDisplayForValue(value); // function you write to determine what's displayed [optional]
  return '<div style="background-color: ' + color + '">' + display + '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you for changing cell color, background or some other CSS styles to use the "cellclassname" instead. Example: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/gridcellclass.htm?arctic

Comment: unless he's going to define a css style for each of the 16 million different colors, that's probably not going to work. easier in this case to just apply the calculated style to the cell in the cell renderer.

Comment: Seriously? Who will ever use 16 million color variations for Grid cells? 1-20 colors are fine for 99% of the apps and with my approach, you would not override the widget's rendering